# Getting numpy error (ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

The following code written using python 3.6. It should create a final matrix containing binary vectors. During the loop, each batch is taken from consecutive vectors to be used by a method `simulate_output()` but eventually the batch is flatten to be a single vector:

```
tmp_list = []
output = []
num_components = 4
dim = 16
total_vectors = 100000

X = np.random.choice(np.array([0, 1], dtype=np.uint8), size=(total_vectors, dim))
num_vectors = np.unique(X, axis=0)

for i in range(0, len(num_vectors), num_components):
    batch = num_vectors[i:(i + num_components)]
    # output.append(simulate_output(batch)) # Comment this line will not solve the error.
    batch = np.hstack(batch)  # to flatten the list into a single vector
    tmp_list.append(batch)

final_matrix = np.array(tmp_list, dtype=np.int8)
print(final_matrix)
```

For some runs I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 65, in <module>
    final_matrix = np.array(tmp_list, dtype=np.int8)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I believe the error is on last line `final_matrix = np.array(tmp_list, dtype=np.int8)` but I have no idea why and how to fix it since in some runs it works while in other runs it does not.

Thank you

Comment: What version of numpy are you running? Running this example (sans the `output.append(...)` line) works fine for me on `'1.14.5'`? I typically have seen this error come up when an element of a list is a list itself. If it breaks for you again I'd inspect the contents of `tmp_list` and make sure it's what you actually expect it to be.

Comment: @Jorden I upgrade to `1.14.5` but still getting the same error. If you try running multiple times, you should get this error.

Comment: I feel stuck. The code seems fine but cannot figure out the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found your problem. 
In this line:

`final_matrix = np.array(tmp_list, dtype=np.int8)`

you expect the `final_matrix` to be a 2-dimensional numpy array. this can be if all the lines have the same length, but this is not exactly your case. your last flatten batch vector is shorter because `len(num_vectors)` is not divided by `num_components`(4).

If you simply put:

```
tmp_list = tmp_list[:-1]
```

after the for loop, everything will be fine. I think one element out of thousands is negligible. If you still don't want to delete it, try to pad it with zeroes to the desired size - `num_components * dim`.

Comment: Great catch! Thank you so much. MAKES SENSE